# How do I configure DNS to access a home computer via a domain name (both on and off local network)?

Tags: dns, remote-desktop

I have a PC at my home that I typically access using Remote Desktop. I would like to be able to use a domain name to access this computer, and be able to use the same domain name regardless of if I am at home (on the same network as that PC) or on the road.

I know that I need to use Dynamic DNS in order to keep my IP address up to date. I have that working now.
I also have port forwarding configured on my router to send traffic on the ports I'm using to that PC's local IP address.
I am able to successfully get to my computer from the outside world using mypc.mysite.com (example url).

However, when I am at home, the mypc.mysite.com domain name needs to resolve to the local IP address, and instead it is getting my "outgoing ip".

I know I can get around this my modifying the "host headers" on my PC, but I want it to work on other devices like my tablet. I also don't want to have to switch my host header file every time I boot depending on where I'm at.

Does anyone have a suggestion?